# Hi, i am running with the following message "PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method PDF::_getpagesize()" , using FPDF

Tags: php, fpdf

Even running basic example of FPDF, I get the following error

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method PDF::_getpagesize()

In XAMPP, more complex code run perfect, I get the error in remote server with ubuntu/php 7.4.33, this is a "new" server, previous server was running "ok" fpdf

Upgrade FPDF v1.84 to v1.85

Comment: Are you sure your code includes the requires FPDF classes?

Comment: Are you sure you have FPDF 1.85 on the server?

Comment: Yes, in the server have the FPDF 1.85 versión ... with the 1.84 i get the same error with "_dochecks()".

Comment: And is a little wierd, the first time i run the script , the file PDF is generated ... the second NOT, even if a close the navigator (brave), open incognito mode, refesh cache ... even in another navigator, that have not previously generated the file (firefox)

Comment: If the server uses OPcache, try disabling it.

Comment: Zend Opcache is ENABLED (Up And Running), let me check that. I think, that is server side problem

Comment: @Olivier disabling OPcache Works, thanks ... but in other server is enabled and is working fine , may be a problem with the server setup

Comment: The version of OPcache is probably not the same.

Answer (score 0):

You call

> PDF::_getpagesize()

instead of

> FPDF::_getpagesize()

and I am pretty sure the PDF class either does not exist, or does not have that method implemented.

Anyway, calling protected methods like that is a bad idea and a bad practice :)

Comment: Is the original code from FPDF, works fine in XAMP, even on "hostinger" , but not in this particular new server

Comment: Run a php file on this new server, that contains a call to `phpinfo()`, and doublecheck if the FPDF extension is really loaded.

Comment: @grinch7117 FPDF is not an extension, it's a regular PHP script.

Comment: Yes, is only a php script... not a extension.